# Why my structure of collection is not expected (not as I need)

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following method of my cart class:

```
public function add($productId) {
        $product = Product::where('id', $productId)->first();
        if (!$product) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->items->has($productId)) {
            $this->items->$productId->qty++;
        } else {
            $this->items->push([$productId => [
                    'name' => $product->title,
                    'price' => $product->price,
                    'is_sale' => $product->is_sale,
                    'sale_price' => $product->sale_price,
                    'sale_percent' => $product->sale_percent,
                    'can_use_promocode' => $product->can_use_promocode,
                    'qty' => 1,
                ]
            ]);
        }
        $this->save();
        return true;
    }
```

But on `dump($cart)` in controller, I got this:

```
+items: Collection {#176 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => {#171 ▼
        +"2": {#164 ▼
          +"name": "101 роза"
          +"price": 4999
          +"is_sale": 0
          +"sale_price": null
          +"sale_percent": null
          +"can_use_promocode": 1
          +"qty": 1
        }
      }      
    ]
  }
```

But I need to:

```
+items: Collection {#176 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      2 => {       
          +"name": "101 роза"
          +"price": 4999
          +"is_sale": 0
          +"sale_price": null
          +"sale_percent": null
          +"can_use_promocode": 1
          +"qty": 1        
      }      
    ]
  }
```

In this case, I thought that `$this->items->push([$productId => ...]` will push the `key => value` pair to collection, but collection creates its own pair, and my pair goes into collection pair. (idk how to describe it correctly, but I think you understand me :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `put()` method instead:

```
->put($key, $data)
```

> The put method sets the given key and value in the collection